# Determining matrix distances between points from different layers along line using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have been looking for how to obtain a matrix of distances between points through a network with QGIS 3.0.3.

I have only found how to obtain a matrix of linear distances, that option is easy to find wiht the basic QGIS options. However, I can not find the way to extract the example I need: to produce a matrix of distances between points of one layer and others of another, through a linear vector, specifically, the distance of several sampling points to several reservoirs through the fluvial network.

I found it in ArcGIS, but I no longer have that program,

Would anyone know it in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I can share my answer from this similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292519/distance-matrix-with-2-point-shapefiles-and-one-street-network/292537#292537).

For the task of obtaining network based distances in the form of distance matrices, you can use the plugin **QNEAT3**. It offers **multiple processing algorithms** that produce origin-destination matrices (OD-Matrix) as line layer, table or csv file out of the box.  All algorithms rely on the `dijkstra()` method in the `qgis.analysis` module, therefore all costs are calculated on the basis of shortest paths and make use of C++ code for faster execution.

You can get more information about the plugin at the **[qgis plugin repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)** and at the plugins **[documentation](https://root676.github.io)**.