# Distance Matrix with 2 point shapefiles and one street network

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3, distance-matrix

I have two point shapefiles (start/destination) and one sort of street network shapefile.
I would like a to create a distance matrix from the start-shapefile to the destination points, using the street network file.
It does not necessarily have to be "shortest path", because mostly there is only one way anyway.

I am using QGIS 3.21 at the moment, but I have 2.18 also, so I don't really care on which one.

Is there a proper solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the plugin **QNEAT3** which is available for QGIS3. It offers **multiple processing algorithms** that produce origin-destination matrices (OD-Matrix) as line layer, table or csv file. It also supports m:n relations which fits to your two layers in your question. All algorithms rely on the `dijkstra()` method in the `qgis.analysis` module, therefore all costs are calculated on the basis of shortest paths.

You can get more information about the plugin at the **[qgis plugin repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)** and at the plugins **[documentation](https://root676.github.io)**.